# Using counters within \index{...} with {index} package NOT {makeidx} package

Tags: macros, counters, expansion, makeindex

[Using counters within \index{...}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83132/using-counters-within-index)
gives solutions to the problem of using counters within the `\index` command when using `\usepackage{makeidx}`, as in

```
    \index{index entry \arabic{counter}}
```

In this case, `\arabic{counter}` is written verbatim

```
    "index entry \arabic{counter}"
```

to the .idx file rather than being first expanded to something like

```
    "index entry 1".
```

Solutions given include defining a new macro `\Index` or use an `\mbox{}`. These solutions work great when using the `makeidx` package.

However, neither solution works when using the `index` package rather than the `makeidx` package. Here is a simple example that was adapted from the above link:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{makeidx}% using this, "\arabic{section}" expands to 1, 2, 3,...
\usepackage{index}% using this, "\arabic{section}" does not expand
\makeindex
\newcommand*{\Index}[1]{\index{#1}}
\begin{document}
\section{First  Section} \Index{first  \arabic{section}}
\section{Second Section} \Index{second \arabic{section}}
\section{Third  Section} \Index{third  \arabic{section}}
\section{Fourth Section} \mbox{\index{fourth \arabic{section}}}
\section{Fifth  Section} \mbox{\index{fifth  \arabic{section}}}
\section{Sixth  Section} \mbox{\index{sixth  \arabic{section}}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

When using \usepackage{makeidx}, the .idx file contains what one might want (expanded counter values):

```
    \indexentry{first 1}{1}
    \indexentry{second 2}{1}
    \indexentry{third 3}{1}
    \indexentry{fourth 4}{1}
    \indexentry{fifth 5}{1}
    \indexentry{sixth 6}{1}
```

However, when using `\usepackage{index}`, the `.idx` file contains what one may not want (verbatim strings/unexpanded counter values):

```
    \indexentry {first \arabic {section}}{1}
    \indexentry {second \arabic {section}}{1}
    \indexentry {third \arabic {section}}{1}
    \indexentry {fourth \arabic {section}}{1}
    \indexentry {fifth \arabic {section}}{1}
    \indexentry {sixth \arabic {section}}{1}
```

I want to use the `index` package for multi-index support. Does anyone have a solution that can be used with the `index` package?

Many many thanks in advance,

```
Dan
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Use the `imakeidx` package in order to get multiple indices together with expansion

Comment: Thank you @Bobyandbob for the welcome message and to @Christian for the package recommendation. Thank you so much. The `imakeidx` package works **great**. I tested it both with the above code and with a "real" project. I did have some issues with it involving apparently failing to successfully automatically call makeindex.exe and crashing when \index{...} included \ifthenelse. But these are separate issues and if they are significant enough, I will post them separately. Actually, I'm not too crazy about automatically calling an external .exe anyways, but would rather call it from a makefile.

Comment: @DanielJ.Greenhoe: You can notify only one of the commenters ;-) And actually `makeindex` is run automatically by `imakeidx`, provided `shell-escape` is enabled

Comment: It's not clear why using an index for producing the table of contents.

Answer (score 1):

The (very old) package `index` overrules the additions in `latex.ltx` about `\protected@write` to the index file, so `\arabic{section}` in an index entry is not expanded first and written then to the `.idx`.

The very sophisticated package `imakeidx` supersedes `index` and allows for multiple indexes, if `shell-escape` (`\write18`) is enabled, `makeindex` or `texindy` is run automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\section{First  Section} \index{first \textbf{Hello} \arabic{section}}
\section{Second Section} \index{second \arabic{section}}
\section{Third  Section} \index{third  \arabic{section}}
\section{Fourth Section} \index{fourth \arabic{section}}
\section{Fifth  Section} \index{fifth  \arabic{section}}
\section{Sixth  Section} \index{sixth  \arabic{section}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]